# Cisco IOS Privilege Level

Tags: router

It is possible to define a privilege level on a Cisco router so that another user can run every command including the enable mode but not create or modify user accounts? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the answer you selected is wrong: there is a way to do it locally.

http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/ios/12_3t/12_3t7/feature/guide/gtclivws.html

It's called Cisco Views and you can tweak who can do what without the need for a server.

Comment: This perfectly answers my issue where I have a very small scale network with no option to use RADIUS or TACACS.

Answer (score 0):

No. The privilege levels are predefined by Cisco and on the router itself there is not much in terms of editing that functionality.

What you can do though is setup TACACS and use that to authenticate. Then you can more easily define what functions certain accounts or groups can do. I do not have much experience with TACACS but I do know that accounts and groups are essentially role based and allowed certain functions based on assigned roles.

TACACS, I think, acts as the authenticator for people trying to login. So authentications are essentially passed to the server with TACACS installed.

Comment: We implemented a similar scheme with a RADIUS server, which had its own set of credentials and therefore, cisco users weren't able to add new users, in case a non-proprietary solution is desirable.